# Meta-annotations and private[this] in Scala

Tags: scala

I've got a little trouble with meta-annotations in Scala. Suppose there is a class

`private class MyClass(@(volatile @field) private[this] var someField: Int) {}`

I want `someField` constructor parameter to be transformed to `private[this]` volatile field. But I've got a warning:

`no valid targets for annotation on variable someField - it is discarded unused. You may specify targets with meta-annotations, e.g. @(volatile @scala.annotation.meta.field @param)`

However, if I replace `private[this]` with just `private` everything is fine.

I use Scala 2.11.6.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using javap you can see that your class does not have a field named someField. The reason is that you didn't use it and it seems that in the case of private[this] variables, scala automatically discard the whole field if not used.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_2
0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>  import scala.annotation.meta._
import scala.annotation.meta._

scala> class MyClass(@(volatile @field) private[this] var someField: Int) {}
<console>:10: warning: no valid targets for annotation on variable someField - i
t is discarded unused. You may specify targets with meta-annotations, e.g. @(vol
atile @scala.annotation.meta.field @param)
       class MyClass(@(volatile @field) private[this] var someField: Int) {}
                      ^
defined class MyClass

scala> :javap -verbose -private MyClass
  Size 562 bytes
  MD5 checksum 05ce62de304576552a958ee79ec4b2b7
  Compiled from "<console>"
public class MyClass
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Utf8               MyClass
   #2 = Class              #1             // MyClass
   #3 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #4 = Class              #3             // java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               <console>
   #6 = Utf8               <init>
   #7 = Utf8               (I)V
   #8 = Utf8               ()V
   #9 = NameAndType        #6:#8          // "<init>":()V
  #10 = Methodref          #4.#9          // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #11 = Utf8               this
  #12 = Utf8               LMyClass;
  #13 = Utf8               someField
  #14 = Utf8               I
  #15 = Utf8
  #16 = Class              #15            //
  #17 = Utf8               $line4/$read
  #18 = Class              #17            // $line4/$read
  #19 = Utf8
  #20 = Utf8
  #21 = Class              #20            //
  #22 = Utf8
  #23 = Class              #22            //
  #24 = Utf8
  #25 = Class              #24            //
  #26 = Utf8               MyClass
  #27 = Utf8               Code
  #28 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #29 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #30 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #31 = Utf8               InnerClasses
  #32 = Utf8               Scala
{
  public MyClass(int);
    descriptor: (I)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>
":()V
         4: return
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   LMyClass;
            0       5     1 someField   I
      LineNumberTable:
        line 14: 0
}
SourceFile: "<console>"
InnerClasses:
     public static #19= #16 of #18; //=class  of class $line4/$read
     public static #19= #21 of #16; //=class  of class
     public static #19= #23 of #21; //=class  of class
     public static #19= #25 of #23; //=class  of class
     public static #26= #2 of #25; //MyClass=class MyClass of class
Error: unknown attribute
  Scala: length = 0x0
```

But if you use that variable in your class, you will see that you have a field which is volatile as you want:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_2
0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>  import scala.annotation.meta._
import scala.annotation.meta._

scala> class MyClass(@(volatile @field) private[this] var someField: Int) {def u
seTheField=print(someField)}
<console>:10: warning: no valid targets for annotation on variable someField - i
t is discarded unused. You may specify targets with meta-annotations, e.g. @(vol
atile @scala.annotation.meta.field @param)
       class MyClass(@(volatile @field) private[this] var someField: Int) {def u
seTheField=print(someField)}
                      ^
defined class MyClass

scala> :javap -verbose -private MyClass
  Size 854 bytes
  MD5 checksum c7e8340b43d0416e81554b586d122a01
  Compiled from "<console>"
public class MyClass
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Utf8               MyClass
   #2 = Class              #1             // MyClass
   #3 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #4 = Class              #3             // java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               <console>
   #6 = Utf8               someField
   #7 = Utf8               I
   #8 = Utf8               useTheField
   #9 = Utf8               ()V
  #10 = Utf8               scala/Predef$
  #11 = Class              #10            // scala/Predef$
  #12 = Utf8               MODULE$
  #13 = Utf8               Lscala/Predef$;
  #14 = NameAndType        #12:#13        // MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
  #15 = Fieldref           #11.#14        // scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef
$;
  #16 = NameAndType        #6:#7          // someField:I
  #17 = Fieldref           #2.#16         // MyClass.someField:I
  #18 = Utf8               scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime
  #19 = Class              #18            // scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime
  #20 = Utf8               boxToInteger
  #21 = Utf8               (I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
  #22 = NameAndType        #20:#21        // boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;

  #23 = Methodref          #19.#22        // scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInt
eger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
  #24 = Utf8               print
  #25 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  #26 = NameAndType        #24:#25        // print:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  #27 = Methodref          #11.#26        // scala/Predef$.print:(Ljava/lang/Obj
ect;)V
  #28 = Utf8               this
  #29 = Utf8               LMyClass;
  #30 = Utf8               <init>
  #31 = Utf8               (I)V
  #32 = NameAndType        #30:#9         // "<init>":()V
  #33 = Methodref          #4.#32         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #34 = Utf8
  #35 = Class              #34            //
  #36 = Utf8               $line4/$read
  #37 = Class              #36            // $line4/$read
  #38 = Utf8
  #39 = Utf8
  #40 = Class              #39            //
  #41 = Utf8
  #42 = Class              #41            //
  #43 = Utf8
  #44 = Class              #43            //
  #45 = Utf8               MyClass
  #46 = Utf8               Code
  #47 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #48 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #49 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #50 = Utf8               InnerClasses
  #51 = Utf8               Scala
{
  private volatile int someField;
    descriptor: I
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_VOLATILE

  public void useTheField();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: getstatic     #15                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lsc
ala/Predef$;
         3: aload_0
         4: getfield      #17                 // Field someField:I
         7: invokestatic  #23                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTi
me.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        10: invokevirtual #27                 // Method scala/Predef$.print:(Lja
va/lang/Object;)V
        13: return
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      14     0  this   LMyClass;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 10: 0

  public MyClass(int);
    descriptor: (I)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: iload_1
         2: putfield      #17                 // Field someField:I
         5: aload_0
         6: invokespecial #33                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>
":()V
         9: return
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      10     0  this   LMyClass;
            0      10     1 someField   I
      LineNumberTable:
        line 10: 0
        line 14: 5
}
SourceFile: "<console>"
InnerClasses:
     public static #38= #35 of #37; //=class  of class $line4/$read
     public static #38= #40 of #35; //=class  of class
     public static #38= #42 of #40; //=class  of class
     public static #38= #44 of #42; //=class  of class
     public static #45= #2 of #44; //MyClass=class MyClass of class
Error: unknown attribute
  Scala: length = 0x0
```

The only problem is that you still get the warning that the volatile annotation is not used, though it is certainly used appropriately in the compiled code. So for this second case, I think it is safe to say displaying that warning is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

No expert here, but the following seems to work:

```
import annotation.meta.field

class Foo(init: Int) {
  @volatile @field private[this] var x: Int = init
}
```

---

Reading the (quite confusing) [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.annotation.meta.package), I have the feeling the problem with your code is the following: `@(volatile @field)` means that the `volatile` annotation is copied to the *field* of `someField` instead of the default target, the constructor parameter. *But:* you haven't specified that `someField` itself should become a field, therefore there is no target. Not sure this makes sense.

Comment: I'm sure I have specified `someField` to become a field by adding `var` to it.